# Узнать дату начала и конца определенной недели определенного года

Tags: php, дата

Есть две переменные:

```
$week // номер недели (51)
$year // номер года (2015)
```

Определить начало и конец определенной недели (текущего года) получилось:

```
$first_day = strtotime($week-date("W")." week -".( date("w")==0?6:date("w")-1 )." day 0:00:00");
$p = date("d.m.Y 23:59:59",$first_day);
$last_day    = date("d.m.Y", strtotime($p.'+6days '));
```

Не знаю насколько написано по феншую, но даты определяет верно.

Надо теперь определить те же даты, но только для 2015 (2014) года. Подскажите, как лучше сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$week=51; $year=2015;
$fy=date("w",mktime(0,0,0,1,1,$year));      // День недели 1 января нужного года
if(!$fy) $fy=7;                             // Коррекция воскресенья
$first=mktime(0,0,0,1,2-$fy+($week-1+($fy/5&1))*7,$year); // Понедельник недели на которой начался год + дней до нужной недели
$last=$first+6*24*3600;                     // Еще 6 дней
if($week<1 || ($week>52 && $year!=date("Y",$first))) print("Incorrect week");

print "First day: ".date("M-d-Y",$first)."  last day: ".date("M-d-Y",$last)."\n";
```

Comment: ваш пример практически правильный, но он выводит даты 52 недели с 21 по 27 декабря, а 51 неделя с 14 по 20 декабря :)

Comment: @thecoder Ну да, согласен, прибавлять 7 дней для первой недели не стоило, поправил. Можно `$week*7-$fy-5`, так короче, но не понятнее :)

Comment: Теперь правильно :)
Но, если указать 
    $week=2; $year=2016;
то он выводит даты первой недели 2016 года с 4 по 10 января, а должно быть с 11 по 17, т.е. вторая неделя

Comment: @thecoder Первая неделя января с 28 дек. 2015 до 3.01.2016, вторая с 4 по 10. Вы уж определитесь с нуля считать недели или с 1 ...

Comment: Во всех календарях период с 28.12 по 03.01 считается 53 неделей.
Можно посмотреть тут http://week.4id.me/2015/53

Comment: @thecoder Тогда найдите правило по которому в части годов недели нумеруются с 1, а в части с 53 и скажите его мне или сами поправьте алгоритм. Просто в том году, который начинается с 53 недели около 25 декабря оказывается 51 неделей, а в других годах, которые начинаются с 1 - 25 декабря в районе 52 недели ...

Comment: Дело в том, что если кол-во последних дней декабря месяца в неделе меньше 3-х, то эти дни считаются как неделя января следующего года, если дней декабря 4 и больше, то они считаются в неделей того года, т.е.2015.

Comment: По ISO 8601 первая неделя не та, что начинается с первого января, а та, что содержит первый четверг года. Вот тут подробнее: http://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/6/86/

Comment: @Mike
исправь строку if($fy<4) $week=$week-1; на
if($fy>4) $week=$week+1; Я отмечу ответ.

Comment: @thecoder Немного по другому изобразил, что бы первоначальные переменные не портить, а то у меня в тестовом цикле постоянно вычиталось из за этого :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function weekFormat(string $year, string $week): string
{
    $yearWeekFormat = $year . 'W' . $week; // '2023W10'

    $start = date('M d',strtotime($yearWeekFormat));
    $end = date('M d', strtotime($yearWeekFormat) + 6 * 24 * 3600);

    return $start . ' - ' . $end;
}
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
function weekFormat(string $year, string $week) : array
{
    if(strlen($week) < 2 ) $week = '0'.$week;
    
    $yearWeekFormat = $year . 'W' . $week; // '2023W10'

    $start = new DateTime($yearWeekFormat);
   
    $end = new DateTime($yearWeekFormat.'+ 6 days');
  
   
    return [
            'week_start' => $start,
            'week_end' => $end
           ];
}

var_dump(weekFormat(2018, 2));


array(2) {
  ["week_start"]=>
  object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-01-08 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
  ["week_end"]=>
  object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(26) "2018-01-14 00:00:00.000000"
    ["timezone_type"]=>
    int(3)
    ["timezone"]=>
    string(3) "UTC"
  }
}
```

в функции проверяем правильность поданного номера недели (она должна быть двузначной). И возвращаем массив объектов DateTime (начало и конец недели)

Comment: задумка хорошая, но исполнение ужасное. Если уж вы начали использовать DateTime, то его и надо использовать везде, не скатываясь к пересчитыванию секундочек.

Comment: @Ипатьев ага, поленился переделывать)) поправил